# How to make the 2nd NIC on the hardware visible to external network through NIC 1?

Tags: linux, networking, routes, network-programming, nic

We have a machine on our network, 4 hops away from my system. The machine has 2 NICs and the first NIC is visible over the general corporate network.( ping succeeds), however, the second NIC on the machine is unreachable, the PING addressed to it dies after reaching some other computer, not even the first publically visible NIC.

S1(my system) --> S2 --> S3 --> S4_I0 ==== S4_I1..? (how to reach this)

Suggest how I can reach the second interface from my system, does it require static routing change only on my system or on the target system as well.

Answer (score 0):

your `S1` requires a route that points to `S4_I0` for at-least
the addresses you want to contact

`S4` requires ip forwarding turned on.

Comment: I turned on the IP forwarding on S4, Now on S1, how do I hardcode path till S4_I0.its a multi hop path..